# Django - how do i force a user to change password on their first login using the last_login field of django.contrib.auth

Tags: python, django

Im using the django.contrib.auth. The code below is the working login function in my views.py

```
    #function based
def user_login(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['login-username']
        password = request.POST['login-password']
        user = authenticate(request, username = username, password = password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)


            return redirect('dashboard')
            
        else:
            
            return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {})

    else:

        return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {})
```

Below is my attempt to check whether if the last_login is NULL. If so, redirect the user to the change-password page. It logs the newly created user (with NULL in the last_login field) but it does not redirect to the change-password page. I have tried changing the placement of the if statement. How do i correctly do this?

```
def user_login(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['login-username']
        password = request.POST['login-password']
        user = authenticate(request, username = username, password = password)

        if user is not None:
            
            if user.last_login == NULL:
                login(request, user)

                return redirect('change-password')

            else:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('dashboard')
            
        else:
            
            return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {})

    else:

        return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the solution to my own question:

```
def user_login(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['login-username']
        password = request.POST['login-password']
        user = authenticate(request, username = username, password = password)

        if user is not None and user.last_login is None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('change-password')
            
        elif user is not None and user.last_login is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('dashboard')

        else:
            messages.error(request, ("Login error!"))
            return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {})
            

    else:

        return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use **last_login** you should create new field also **created_at** for example and compare this two field with redirect user

or

I suggest to add new field (boolean field) and but the default value for it is false, when any user login check if it **False or True**, in the first login redirect user to change password and **update this field to True**

good luck